# relational database model

Tags: database, foreign-keys, relational-database

Lets say we have three tables: Cars, People, Companies.

We want the owner of the car to be a people or a company. The structure of the Cars table is: Car_id, Car_model, Owner_id

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you change the structure? What you have is far from ideal.

Comment: I mean are you allowed to add or change columns in the `cars` table?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the current structure of the cars table, then you could add new table called `owners` with the following columns:

`number` **id** -- unique key
`number` **owner_id** -- this is the actual owner id
`char` **owner_type** -- this is a value indicating whether the owner is a person or a company

You will then need to cross reference `cars` with `owners` and look at the value of `owner_type` to determine which table to get your owner data from.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention (rather important):

In the `cars` table, populate the `owner_id` with the `owners.id` column.

Answer (score 0):

What about having another field in Cars table as "Owner_type_id" which will determine if owner is a person or a company or any other thing. Of course, you should keep another table "Owner_Types" for this scenario to work.

Answer (score 0):

As Igby mentioned, your existing structure is far from ideal, but if you're stuck with it, one option is to have a new `Owner` table that has the `owner_id` from the `Car` table as well as a `person_id` and a `company_id`, only one of which would need to be populated.